# Statically define a member using the dynamically determined class type

Tags: c#, events, .net-3.5, types

I'm trying to create an event delegate where the parameter is strongly typed to match the current class, like this:

```
public class HPCRequest
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(HPCRequest request);
    public event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;
```

The problem is that the point of this class is to be inherited, and what I really want is for all those inheriting classes to have the "RequestComplete" event, where the delegate is typed for that class:

```
public class HPCGetConfig : HPCRequest
{
    //I want this class to effectively inherit something like this:
    //public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(HPCGetConfig request);
```

This is because currently, when I have a function that handles one of my "RequestComplete" events, I currently have to do this:

```
    myGetConfigRequest.RequestComplete += new HPCRequest.RequestCompleteHandler(HPCGetExpectedLosses_RequestComplete);

void HPCGetConfig_RequestComplete(HPCRequest request)
{
    HPCGetConfig thisRequest = request as HPCGetConfig;
    //This should be strongly typed in the first place.
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
    request.RequestComplete += new HPCGetConfig.RequestCompleteHandler(HPCGetConfig_RequestComplete);
    request.SendRequestAsync();
}

void HPCGetConfig_RequestComplete(HPCGetConfig request)
{
    request.RequestComplete -= HPCGetConfig_RequestComplete;
```

---

**Attempts**

I've tried this:

```
public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler<T>(T request) where T : HPCRequest; 
public event RequestCompleteHandler<T> RequestComplete;
```

but when I try to invoke the event from within the base class using `RequestComplete(this);`, I get a compile time error: `Delegate 'RequestCompleteHandler' has some invalid arguments.

This happens whether or not I set up the entire `HPCRequest` class as `HPCRequest<T>` by going:

```
public class HPCRequest<T> where T : HPCRequest<T> 
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler<T>(T request); 
    public event RequestCompleteHandler<T> RequestComplete;

public class HPCGetConfig : HPCRequest<HPCGetConfig> { ...
```

The same error occurs when I try to invoke the event: `RequestComplete(this);`

I've also tried all forms of creating the delegate and event and overriding them, such as in doing:

```
public class HPCRequest
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(HPCRequest request);
    public virtual event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;


public sealed class HPCGetConfig : HPCRequest
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(HPCGetConfig request);
    public override event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;
```

But this gives me a compile time error because I cannot override the RequestComplete event with one of a different delegate type.

Any other ideas?

---

**Edit**

Templating the entire HPCRequest class is not an option, after a very thorough attempt, I see that it just screws up every attempt to use the type HPCRequest as a placeholder for any request type. If this solution is going to work, the class `HPCRequest` must be able to be instantiated and inherited from without specifying a type parameter. I'll need a solution that doesn't require templating `HPCRequest`.

To make sure everyone know exactly how I'm trying to use this, I pasted some sample code into pastebin that should let you experiment with ways of getting this event templating working without breaking anything. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/bbEYgLj1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's can't be done**.

I've ended up having to cast the delegate everywhere it's used.

Happy to change the accepted answer if anything ever shows otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

What you could try:

```
public abstract class HPCRequest<T> where T : HPCRequest<T>
{
  public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(T request);
  public event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;

  protected void RaiseRequestComplete(T request)
  {
    if (RequestComplete != null)
    {
      RequestComplete(request);
    }
  }
}

public class Foo : HPCRequest<Foo>
{
  public void Bar()
  {
    RaiseRequestComplete(this);
  }
}

public class Example
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    var request = new Foo();

    request.RequestComplete += RequestComplete;
  }

  static void RequestComplete(Foo request)
  {
    // It's a Foo!
  }
}
```

This self-referential generic constraint allows what you want I think. I added the `protected RaiseRequestCompleted` so you can still raise the event from classes that inherit from HCPRequest. Otherwise, only `HCPRequest` would be allowed to do so.

**UPDATE**: I updated the code to pass `this` and added sample code that matches your desired result.

Comment: I think the type parameters on the delegate and event are unnecessary and in fact conflict with the type parameter on the class.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. I copy-pasted that bit from the question :)

Comment: See above comments to similar suggestions. `RequestComplete(this);` gives me an error. My structure doesn't support a 'RaiseRequestComplete`. I can't do `new Foo()` like you do because HPCRequest instances need to pass themselves as the event parameter.

Comment: @JulianR - I've edited my attempts into the question if you would like to follow up.

Comment: @Alain - `RequestComplete(this)` gives you an error because you can't raise an event outside of the class that it was declared in, not even if that was a base class. However, that's why I added the `RaiseRequestComplete` method to `HCPRequest`, it's `protected` so only subclasses can call it. I don't see why you couldn't add the method to `HCPRequest` like I did and pass in `this` instead of `new Foo()`. I'll update my answer to pass `this` as the argument.

Comment: Alright, I think where we're not seeing eye to eye is that the base class itself needs to be able to call `RaiseRequestComplete` in a virtual method that gets overridden. Calling `RaiseRequestComplete` from the base class is currently giving a compile error (invalid arguments). Remember that the base class can be instantiated on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generic type parameter for this purposes so each class inherited from HPCRequest must specify a generic type parameter. Also I would suggest marking classes which are designed to be a base class by `abstract` modifier to avoid explicit instantiation:

```
public abstract class HPCRequest<TRequest>
  where TRequest: class
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(TRequest request);
    public event RequestCompleteHandler<TRequest> RequestComplete;
}


public sealed class HPCGetConfig : HPCRequest<HPCGetConfig>
{
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a step in the right direction, but it's wrong to assume HPCRequest is abstract. The **main** point of that class is to be inherited but it can be instantiated, and it contains implementations of certain methods. When I try to make the class invoke its RequestComplete event using: `if (RequestComplete != null) RequestComplete(this);` - I get an error: `Delegate RequestCompleteHandler has some invalid arguments.`

Comment: Can I support the base class by defining the following: `public class HPCRequest : HPCRequest<HPCRequest> { }`?  \*edit\* I don't think so, because then my other classes can't be cast to this class anymore.

Comment: I've edited my attempts into the question if you would like to follow up.

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the type parameter of the abstract class to be derived from the abstract class itself. It seems strange, but you can set it up like this:

```
public abstract class HPCRequest<T> where T : HPCRequest<T>
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(T request);
    public event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;
}

public class DerivedHPCRequest : HPCRequest<DerivedHPCRequest>
{

}
```

Comment: This is breaking my code everywhere I use the base class, such as `HPCRequest anyRequestHolder = ...` I don't always want an instance of HPCRequest to be strongly typed.

Comment: I've edited my attempts into the question if you would like to follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is a great candidate for **explicitly implementing a non-generic interface in a generic base class**.  I'm not certain that I am completely understanding the desired functionality, but I think I did.  I wrote some code (below) that should get you started.

As a side note, there isn't a real reason to declare the delegates.  For consistency with [MSDN Event Design standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx), your solution would use `EventHandler<T>` and a custom `EventArgs` implementation.

## Code

```
//  this is a sample program using the pattern i am recommending
//  I'm pretty sure this is what you wanted your code to look like? 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var request = new HPCGetConfig();
        request.RequestComplete += HandleConfigRequestCompleted;
        request.SendAsync();
    }

    static void HandleConfigRequestCompleted(object sender, RequestCompleteEventArgs<HPCGetConfig> e)
    {
        var request = e.Request;
        // do something with the request
    }
}

//  the non-generic event args class 
public abstract class RequestCompleteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public abstract Type RequestType { get; }
    public abstract object RequestObject { get; set; }
}

// the generic event args class
public class RequestCompleteEventArgs<T> : RequestCompleteEventArgs
{
    private T m_Request;


    public T Request
    {
        get { return m_Request; }
        set { m_Request = value; }
    }

    public override Type RequestType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public override object RequestObject
    {
        get { return Request; }
        set
        {
            if (!(value is T))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type.", "value");
            }
            m_Request = (T)value;
        }
    }
}

//  the non-generic interface
public interface IHPCRequest
{
    event EventHandler<RequestCompleteEventArgs> RequestComplete;
}

//  the generic base class
public abstract class HPCRequest<T> : IHPCRequest 
    where T : HPCRequest<T>
{
    //  this sanitizes the event handler, and makes it callable 
    //  whenever an event handler is subscribed to the non-generic 
    //  interface
    private static EventHandler<RequestCompleteEventArgs<T>> ConvertNonGenericHandler(EventHandler<RequestCompleteEventArgs> handler)
    {
        return (sender, e) => handler(sender, e);
    }

    //  this object is for a lock object for thread safety on the callback event
    private readonly object Bolt = new object();

    //  This determines whether the send method should raise the completed event.
    //  It is false by default, because otherwise you would have issues sending the request asynchronously
    //  without using the SendAsync method.
    public bool AutoRaiseCompletedEvent { get; set; }

    //  This is used to ensure that RequestComplete event cannot fire more than once
    public bool HasRequestCompleteFired { get; private set; }

    //  declare the generic event
    public event EventHandler<RequestCompleteEventArgs<T>> RequestComplete;

    //  explicitly implement the non-generic interface by wiring the the non-generic
    //  event handler to the generic event handler
    event EventHandler<RequestCompleteEventArgs> IHPCRequest.RequestComplete
    {
        add { RequestComplete += ConvertNonGenericHandler(value); }
        remove { RequestComplete -= ConvertNonGenericHandler(value); }
    }

    //  I'm not 100% clear on your intended functionality, but this will call an overrideable send method
    //  then raise the OnRequestCompleted event if the AutoRaiseCompletedEvent property is set to 'true'
    public void Send()
    {
        SendRequest((T)this);

        if(AutoRaiseCompletedEvent) 
        {
            OnRequestCompleted((T)this);
        }
    }

    public void SendAsync()
    {
        // this will make the event fire immediately after the SendRequest method is called
        AutoRaiseCompletedEvent = true;
        new Task(Send).Start();
    }

    //  you can make this virtual instead of abstract if you don't want to require that the Request 
    //  class has the Send implementation
    protected abstract void SendRequest(T request);

    //  this raises the RequestCompleted event if it is the first call to this method.  
    //  Otherwise, an InvalidOperationException is thrown, because a Request can only 
    //  be completed once
    public void OnRequestCompleted(T request)
    {
        bool invalidCall = false;
        Exception handlerException = null;
        if (HasRequestCompleteFired)
            invalidCall = true;
        else
        {
            lock(Bolt)
            {
                if(HasRequestCompleteFired)
                {
                    invalidCall = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (RequestComplete != null)
                    {
                        // because you don't want to risk throwing an exception
                        // in a locked context
                        try
                        {
                            RequestComplete(this, new RequestCompleteEventArgs<T> { Request = request });
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            handlerException = e;
                        }
                    }
                    HasRequestCompleteFired = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(invalidCall)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("RequestCompleted can only fire once per request");
        }
        if(handlerException != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The RequestComplete handler threw an exception.");
        }
    }


}

// a sample concrete implementation
public class HPCGetConfig : HPCRequest<HPCGetConfig>
{
    protected override void SendRequest(HPCGetConfig request)
    {
        // do some configuration stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Nah, that has more or less the functionality my attached code already has. The only functionality I wanted to add was a strongly typed event args. In your example, you still have to cast the request completed args to the appropriate request type.

Comment: @Alain, You are mistaken.  The `RequestComplete` event has a signature of `void HandleEvent(object sender, RequestCompleteEventArgs<TRequest>)`, and you can access the "appropriate request type, via the `Request` Property.  You can also access it as an `object` via the `RequestObject` property.  Both options are available with this implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would have to create an abstract base class that can of cause not be instantiated:

```
public abstract class HPCRequestBase<T> where T : HPCRequestBase<T>
{
    public delegate void RequestCompleteHandler(T request);
    public event RequestCompleteHandler RequestComplete;

    protected void OnRequestComplete(T request)
    {
        if (RequestComplete != null) {
            RequestComplete(request);
        }
    }

    public void Test( )
    {
        OnRequestComplete((T)this);
    }

}

public class HPCRequest : HPCRequestBase<HPCRequest>
{
    public void Test2()
    {
        OnRequestComplete(this);
    }
}

public class HPCRequestConfig : HPCRequestBase<HPCRequestConfig>
{
    // Derived from the base class, not from HPCRequest 
}
```

Also 'this' has to be casted to T: `OnRequestComplete((T)this);`

This test runs without an error:

```
var hpcr = new HPCRequest();
hpcr.Test();
hpcr.Test2();
```

Comment: Kind of duplicate of some other suggestions, but the main problem with this is that the base class is abstract, so I cannot cast the implementations (like `HPCRequestConfig`) to a `HPCRequestBase<T>` and invoke virtual methods. This functionality is required by functions that act on all kinds of HPCRequests, where the non-generic type isn't known. You can look at the pasteBin code attached to the question to get a feel for how it's being used.

Comment: You cannot cast to an open generic base class. What you could have, is a non-generic base class. Then derive specific classes and let them implement a generic interface. You can also inject stuff having very specific types through the constructor, since the constructor is not part of the base class or an interface.